# Group bar chart graph with two different y-axis scales in gnuplot?

Tags: graph, gnuplot, bar-chart

Good day,

I need to create a group bar chart graph with different scales.

Consider following data example:

```
Metric A B
Group1 10 1500
Group2 20 4000
```

I am using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758057/histogram-using-gnuplot-with-multiple-y-axes) and this code:

```
reset
set style histogram cluster gap 1
set style data histograms
set style fill solid 1.00 border
set yrange [0:]
set ytics nomirror
set y2range [0:]
set y2tics
```

set key right autotitle columnheader
plot 'file.dat' u 2 every ::::0, '' u 3:xtic(1) every ::::0,\
     newhistogram lt 1 at 1,\
     'file.dat' u 2 every ::1::1 axes x1y1, '' u 3:xtic(1) every ::1::1 axes x1y2

The code above creates this plot:

[image]

However, what I need is:

1. Left Y scale to be [0:20]
2. All numbers from A to be plotted according to left Y scale
3. All numbers from B to be plotted according to right Y scale
4. If possible, to put labels on both left and right Y scale.
5. If possible, to have only one pair of A and B in the legend.

This way, the Violet color Bars will be much higher, and dependent only on column A number range.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Show how you have done this plot, and search for the `y2` axis. And think about how someone else should know which bar belongs to which axis.

Comment: If you could elaborate more on the question, including the code you used so far, would be much helpful. In the meantime, have a look at this http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/multiaxis.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using 2 axis using `y2`:

```
set ytics nomirror
set y2tics
set yrange [0:20]
set y2range [0:] 
set key right

label = "MyLabel"
set ylabel label
set y2label label

set style data histograms
plot 'histplot.dat' using 2 ti col axis x1y1, '' u 3:xticlabels(1) ti col axis x1y2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem. Setting the yrange also to [0:], plots the graph like a charm and set the scales automatically. I noticed I am getting some needles on x axis right in the middle of first bar of each group bar. Is there a way to get rid of them? Once again, thank you!

Comment: @DarkTemplar I guess you need to use `unset xtics` to remove the "needles"